# Proverbs 17:7 - Why still less is false speech to a prince?

Tags: proverbs

Proverbs 17:7

> Fine speech is not becoming to a fool;
>
> still less is false speech to a prince.

I understand the first verse as a fool can't say fine speech. But the second verse: "still less is false speech to a prince", does this mean princes won't make wrong speech? I don't really understand this verse, who are these princes and how they won't make wrong speech?

Comment: *(un)becoming* means *(un)worthy*, not *(im)possible*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to rewrite the sentence structure a bit. This is saying that a prince *is* capable of "false speech" and it is even more unbecoming than the fool with "fine speech".

So the NET translates the verse this way

> Excessive speech is not becoming for a fool; how much less are lies for a ruler!

And the Amplified version says:

> Excellent speech does not benefit a fool [who is spiritually blind], Much less do lying lips benefit a prince.

Answer (score 0):

> Eloquence befits not a fool,
>
> still less lying on the lips of princes.

Its meaning is a 'proverbial' construction (or, just a Hebrew parallelism) meaning that fools are not wont to speak eloquence—it doesn't suit them, as fools (*Prov 18:2; **19:10***). More still is it unbecoming of his dignity that a prince should be found lying, something opposite to that which is expected of them that bear rule (*Wis 1:1; 6:6; Jas 3:1*).